# How to "crop" a matrix while keeping the byte alignment?

Tags: c, opencv

Let's say I have a 100x100 matrix A, and I want to get another 100x50 matrix B containing only the 50 first columns of A.
The easiest method is to use cvGetSubRect, but this doesn't copy the values, it just gives me a header pointing to the data of A and "skips" the columns I don't need, while it is crucial for my application that the data in B can be read with continuously.

What is the most elegant way to do this in OpenCV? I don't mind actually copying the data from A to B but I am assuming there is a special function to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Mat::copyTo()` to do a full copy.  If necessary (e.g., if the shape is wrong), this will reallocate data for the target matrix.

Since the question is actually tagged "c", I will mention for completeness that the C-API copy function is `cvCopy()` .